# How to handle an HTTP request that stops sending data

Tags: node.js, http

I'm trying to download videos from some URLs and for some reason the downloads will sometimes stop before they're complete - as in `res.on('data', ...)` will stop being called (using `https.get`) before the response has completed. I would like to be able to detect this and retry the request after a given time, but I'm having a hard time getting working code for it. I'm hoping there would be a built in way to deal with something like this that I'm missing. I've already tried setting a timeout for the request and setting a timeout for the response and neither of those seem to do the trick.

Current attempt:

```js
async function downloadVideo(send) {
    try {
        https.get(downloadUrl, res => {
            let timerId;

            res.on(`data`, (c) => {
                clearTimeout(timerId);
                timerId = setTimeout(() => {
                    res.destroy();
                    console.log(`retrying`, name);
                    downloadVideo(send);
                }, 2000);

                if (!throttle) {
                    send(`PercentDownloaded`, [
                        index,
                        100 * fileSize(filePath) / res.headers[`content-length`]
                    ]);

                    throttle = true;
                    setTimeout(() => throttle = false, 500);
                }
            });

            res
                .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filePath))
                .on(`finish`, () => {
                    clearTimeout(timerId);
                    send(`Done`, index);
                });
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(name, error);
        send(`DownloadError`, index);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please post your code?

Comment: @Nonik done (not a long enough comment)

Comment: It seems like `request.setTimeout` is what I was looking for. Turns out it's different than the timeout option.